# MySQL where-in statement should return records by order of where-in

Tags: mysql, where-in

Let's say I have following SQL statement:

```
SELECT * FROM someTable where id in (4,5,2,3,1);
```

This will return all records from `someTable` which have an `id` equals to 4, 5, 2, 3 or 1. The order of which they are returned is:

```
id data
============
1 data
2 data
3 data
4 data
5 data
============
```

How can the returned values be like the order of the where-in clause? So the returned order should be:

```
============
4 data
5 data
2 data
3 data
1 data
============
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `order by field`

```
order by field(id,4,5,2,3,1) ;
```

Comment: I am accepting this as an answer since this fills my needs. I didn't know this existed, thanks!